# awk Time Finding

Tags: awk

I have a text file on Linux, and I want to use awk to change the date part and put in the current date.
Of course, I wrote this and it works, but I have to give it the date manually, and what I want is for it to automatically replace the day's date.

Code :

```
awk '{gsub(/ISODate\(\"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9]/,"ISODate(\"2022-10-02");print}' rasoul-02.json
```

Comment: Simple substitutions on individual lines is what `sed` is best at, why not use it for this?

Comment: If you have a JSON file, using a JSON-aware tool such as `jq` would be safer and cleaner than using `awk`. Could you possibly post a sample input file, so that we can show how to do this with `jq` too (it should be quite easy, I believe)?

Comment: Is your input data files actually a MongoDB database dump?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the date to `awk` as a variable:

```
awk -v date="$(date +%F)" '{gsub(/ISODate\("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9]/,"ISODate(\""date"\"");print}'
```

If you can use GNU awk (`gawk`), you can also simplify your regular expression significantly:

```
gawk -v date="$(date +%F)" '{
    gsub(/ISODate\("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/,"ISODate(\""date);
    print
}' rasoul-02.json
```

However, this is all a pretty bad idea. If you are working with JSON files, there are dedicated JSON parsers like `jq` that can do this in a safer and simpler way. I strongly urge you to post the actual file so we can provide a better answer.

Comment: `{4}` is standard (though not supported by all `awk` implementations). Note that leaving `$(date...)` unquoted in shells like sh or bash means invoking split+glob which is not needed nor wanted here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, it is standard, which is why I was quite surprised that mawk doesn't support it, but I tested and also confirmed in mawk's man page that it does indeed not support the `{N} ` quantifiers. Since mawk is the default awk on Ubuntu, I felt I should clarify that. As for quoting yes, true, but it's a safe string by definition which is why I didn't bother. But yeah, fair enough.

Comment: `{x,y}` were not in EREs (egrep, awk) initially. `\{x,y\}` was added to BRE, but could not be added to ERE without breaking backward compatibility. POSIX introduced `grep -E` and mandated `{x,y}` in EREs but several implementation refused to add it to their awk/egrep to avoid breaking scripts. `mawk` is not the only implementation that doesn't support it. All `grep` implementations that support `-E` support `{x,y}` but not all `egrep`s do.

Comment: There's no *safe string* in the face or split+glob or there are only safe strings if you can make some assumption on the current value of `$IFS`. See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to obtain the ISO format of today's date.

- With an external command: `date +'%F'`
- With a shell command: `printf '%(%F)T\n' -1`
- In some awk versions: `strftime("%F")`

The most general (portable) solution would be using `date`:

```
awk '{gsub(/ISODate\([0-9]{4}([-][0-9]{2}){2}\)/,"ISODate("isodate")")}1
    ' isodate=$(date +'%F') rasoul-02.json
```

A possible solution using the shell internal date format would be:

```
$ printf -v isodate '%(%F)T' '-1';
$ awk '{gsub(/ISODate[(]["][0-9]{4}([-][0-9]{2}){2}["][)]/,"ISODate(===\""isodate"\")")}1
      ' isodate=$isodate rasoul-02.json
```

And using the `strftime` function of the GNU awk (and some other):

```
awk '{ gsub( /ISODate[(]["][0-9]{4}([-][0-9]{2}){2}["][)]/ , "ISODate(\"" strftime("%F") "\")" )}1
      ' rasoul-02.json
```